# Как получить аргументы процесса?

Tags: c#, парсер, командная-строка

Как получить аргументы, c которыми запустили нужный процесс? В формате аргумент-значение.

Comment: В аргументы метода Main смотрели? Что вас в них не устраивает?

Comment: Другой процесс, в смысле? не свои аргументы? Ну спроси, скажем, у WMI -  `Win32_Process.CommandLine`.

Comment: допустим процесс test.exe -all или test -p "123" - их как получить на C#?

Answer (score 6):

Аргументы командной строки передаются в функцию `Main`, которая есть в каждом приложении на дотнете (ну, кроме специализированных, где эта деталь скрыта). Также командная строка целиком доступна через [`Environment.CommandLine`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.commandline).

В функцию `Main` аргументы передаются "распарсенными" в соответствии с тем, как аргументы понимает операционная система. Например, аргументы `-all -p "123"` будут интепретированы как три строки: `"-all"`, `"-p"`, `"123"`. Вне `Main` эти аргументы можно получить с помощью [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs).

---

Если вам нужна работа с аргументами в более удобной форме, то вы можете воспользоваться одним из многочисленных пакетов с парсерами командной строки на NuGet. Они вам позволят интерпретировать аргументы как имена и значения, преобразуют типы значений, сгенерируют справку и т.п.

Любой парсер, который вы найдёте, будет выдавать пары аргумент-значение. Есть различия в поддерживаемом синтаксисе, типах аргументов, API (декларативные, императивные, ни рыба ни мясо), но базовый функцонал у всех единый.

Большой популярностью пользуется [CommandLineParser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommandLineParser/), но я бы предостерёг от его использования: старая адекватная версия библиотеки заброшена и страдает от нескольких багов, новая версия переписана в совершенно упоротом стиле, неподдерживаема, и светлого будущего не видать. Список популярных библиотек:

- [CommandLineParser](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline) — самая популярная, самая упоротая
- [FluentCommandLineParser](https://github.com/fclp/fluent-command-line-parser) — другая популярная
- [PowerArgs](https://github.com/adamabdelhamed/PowerArgs) — ещё одна популярная
- [System.CommandLine](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/tree/master/src/System.CommandLine) — часть Core FX Lab от Microsoft, кандидат на включение в дотнет
- [CommandLineUtils](https://github.com/natemcmaster/CommandLineUtils) — изначально часть Microsoft ASP.NET MVC, сейчас поддерживается другим разрабом

Comment: Как понимает ОС или как понимает шарп?

Comment: @Qwertiy У винды есть свой парсер командной строки, который обрабатывает кавычки, экранизацию и прочее в соответствии с сишными правилами (`CommandLineToArgvW`). Использует .NET эту функцию или эквивалент реализован на C# — не знаю, смотреть надо, но каких-либо различий со стандартным виндовым парсером я не замечал.

Comment: А если запустить не под виндой? Я замечал, что у nodejs специфичный парсинг и с виндовым он не сходится :(

Comment: @Qwertiy Думаю, что в .NET на остальных осях эмулируют виндовый парсер. Опять-таки, надо смотреть сорцы.

Comment: А какой парсер посоветуете? парсинг нужен в формате аргумент:значение

Comment: @Вячеслав Добавил информацию о парсерах в ответ.